# How to properly load html code on a jquery dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dialog

im trying to load a piece of html inside a jquery dialog, this piece of code is located in a separated file, but sometimes fails to load it right. It happens like this :

This is how it should have been displayed.

[image: Everything fine]

But sometimes(many times actually) does this:

[image: Oh! No!]

This is the code that calls the dialog

```
        .click(function(){
        var me = this;
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"../CuentaEquipo.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data:"idEquipo="+$(this).attr("idEquipo")+"&idTorneo="+$(this).attr("idTorneo")+"&action=100",
            success:function(data){
                if(data.data == 1){
                    var cuentas = $("#cuentas").load("AdministracionCuentaEquipo.html").dialog({
                        stack:true,
                        autoOpen:false,
                        close:function(){
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    });
                    cuentas.dialog('open');
                }
```

And this is the code i'm trying to load (AdministracionCuentaEquipo.html)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#accioncuentas").tabs();
$(".test").button().click(function(){alert("ASDF")});
</script>
<div id="accioncuentas">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#abonos">Abonos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#cargos">Cargos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#saldos">Saldos</a></li>
    </ul>

<div id="abonos">
    <button class="test">HI</button>
</div>

<div id="cargos">
    <button class="test">HI</button>
</div>

<div id="saldos">
    <button class="test">HI</button>
</div>
</div>
```

The only thing that works is closing and opening when this happens, but it's very annoying to do that. It's there any fix or i'm doing something wrong with the ajax or anything else?

Thanks .

Comment: $("#accioncuentas").tabs(); when execution of this statement the DOM is not ready, so place it last or in onLoad function.

Comment: Thanks! I also going to try this later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are creating/opening the dialog before the HTML has properly been parsed.

From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function):

> If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed.

So try changing this code:

```
var cuentas = $("#cuentas").load("AdministracionCuentaEquipo.html").dialog({
    stack:true,
    autoOpen:false,
    close:function(){
            $(this).dialog("close");
    }
});
```

to:

```
var cuentas = $("#cuentas").load("AdministracionCuentaEquipo.html", function(e)
{
    $("#cuentas").dialog({
        stack:true,
        autoOpen:false,
        close:function(){
                $(this).dialog("close");
        }
});
```

EDIT: the line `$("#accioncuentas").tabs();` might also fire too early, so you could change that script tag to wrap it in a function and call that function in your other code.
Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function InitializeTabs()
    {
        $("#accioncuentas").tabs();
    }
</script>
```

and then add the line `InitializeTabs();` to your code, for example above the line `$("#cuentas").dialog({`.

SECOND EDIT: I actually think Dasarp is correct in saying that the `$("#accioncuentas").tabs();` is the main problem. Either wrap it in a function as I suggested, or move the entire `<script>` tag down to the bottom of the file (below **all** your HTML).

Comment: Thanks! That worked like a charm, no doubt i have plenty to learn of javascript and jquery. Thanks again, and have a fantastic day!

Comment: I will try the Dasarp solution later.

Comment: @BasilioHinojosadelCastillo Which part of the solution fixed your problem? Getting the `$("#accioncuentas").tabs();` to fire later, or changing the `.load()` callback?

Comment: Just changing the load callback